# querying in mezmo ie logdna with regular expressions

Tags: logdna

TAYQ yes I've searched mezmo.com and google and duck duck go, and no, nothing comes up under specific UI search line expressions that work

I can search for

```
genesis/volume/deletionsucceeded OR genesis/volume/modificationsucceeded
```

in my logs, and that works

but trying to search by ANY reasonable regex modicum of that such as:

```
genesis/volume/*succeeded
- or - 
genesis/volume/[a-z]+succeeded
- or maybe we need quotes
"genesis/volume/[a-z]+succeeded"
```

fails to return any results.

How would I accomplish the above?